# VS 2022 Remote File Explorer

Tags: raspbian, ssh

I'm trying to connect to my Raspberry PI directly from Visual Studio 2022, and I can't seem to get this new feature to work:
[image]

I can easily connect to the PI over SSH, so I don't understand why this dos not work using the private key.  It also gives no error message:
[image]

After I hovered over a red box (very unintentional), the tooltip gave this bit of info:
[image]

As I'm security is something that drives me crazy, i'm not sure how to get this "feature" to work.  I'm back to the SSH and my basic commands that I know.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read [the guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/linux/connect-to-your-remote-linux-computer?view=msvc-170) carefully?
Maybe you created a wrong type of the key, I just had this problem myself, but fixed it using the **-m pem** swith when generating RSA key.
[image]